# The response type after using HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.OfString()

Tags: java, httpresponse

```
class Main{
    //we can use class HttpClient 
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MmlRZZxTqk

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {    
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        // .GET() this line is optional because it is default
        .header("accept","application/json")
        .uri(URI.create("https://whatever.com"))
        .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        System.out.println(response.body()); 
        System.out.println(response.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

So I read the documentation about the BodyHandlers.ofString() method, my understanding is that it will parse the value of the response variable into a String. But if that's the case then why when I ran this line

```
        System.out.println(response.getClass().getName());
```

the outcome is jdk.internal.net.http.HttpResponseImpl? I read another post saying that you should never use any class in idk.internal.*, so am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

> so am I doing anything wrong ?

There is nothing wrong here, `HttpResponse` is the interface. So [`response.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) is fine to return any implementation that implement `HttpResponse`(`HttpResponseImpl` in this case).

> I read another post saying that you should never use any class in idk.internal.*

This means that you should not declare/initialise this class directly in your code. For example, you should not write something like:

```java
HttpResponseImpl<String> response;
```

The principal behind is we should depend on the interface, but not the implementation details, more details can be found in [JEP 260](https://openjdk.org/jeps/260)